# How to modify landing page after login in lifray?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui, liferay-hook

I have 4 different organization and some users are associated to it. I have separate site for each organization. my requirement is If I am user of organization A , On login I should be able to redirect to my organization site.

> eg: localhost:8080/web/org-A/home

How can I achieve this requirement. As per my knowledge I need to create post login hook by which user will get redirected to its own site.
I would like to know if any configuration in poral-ext.property is available by which user can redirect to his own site automatically after login.

Comment: With pasting exactly your question title I found quite a lot of information on google, including some existing forum discussion, an app on marketplace etc. What did you try so far? What were the limitations?

Comment: I agree with @OlafKock. There is lot of information available on this topic. Here is an app that would help you to achieve what you want : https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/17676547

Comment: Custom Landing Page App in the market place is the quick solution you have.